# How to play large audio/video files in android.?

Tags: android, audio, android-intent

I'm listing the audio and video files from sdcard/internal storage and playing(see below code), but it's not working for large audio/video files. It's showing  **OutOfMemoryError**, how to remove this error?

```
public class GetPath extends Activity {

    String imagePath;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.get_path);

    }

    public void getAudio(View v){

        Intent i = new Intent(this, AudioList.class);
        startActivityForResult(i, 11);
    }

    public void getVideo(View v) throws IOException {

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, VideoList.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 111);

    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){

        TextView imagePathText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.image_path);
        TextView audioPathText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.audio_path);
        TextView videoPathText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.video_path);

        byte [] audioByte = new byte[0];
        byte[] videoByte = new byte[0];

        if(requestCode == 11){
            if(resultCode == 300){

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),""+data.getExtras().getString("audioPath"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                audioPathText.setText(data.getExtras().getString("audioPath"));
                imagePath = data.getExtras().getString("audioPath");


                playMp3(audioByte);
                MediaPlayer m = new MediaPlayer();

                try {
                    m.setDataSource(imagePath);
                   m.prepare();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                m.start();

            }
        }else if(requestCode == 111){
            if(resultCode == 301){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),""+data.getExtras().getString("videoPath"),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                videoPathText.setText(data.getExtras().getString("videoPath"));
                imagePath = data.getExtras().getString("videoPath");


                Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.play_video);
        dialog.setTitle("video");
        final VideoView videoplay = (VideoView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.videoPlayer);
        final Button play = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.play);
        videoplay.setVideoPath(imagePath);
        play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(fff){
                    videoplay.start();
                    fff =false;
                }else{
                    videoplay.pause();
                    fff =true;
                }

            }
        });
        dialog.show();
            }
        }

    }
```

**Below code to convert the audio/video file in to byte array(can't convert large file ex: i used 70 MD audio file and 35MB video file)**

```
public byte[] convert(String path) throws IOException {

    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(path);
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[] b = new byte[10024];

    for (int readNum; (readNum = fis.read(b)) != -1;) {
        bos.write(b, 0, readNum);
    }

    byte[] bytes = bos.toByteArray();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+bytes.length, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    return bytes;
}
```

**Below code to convert byte array to audio file()**

```
private void playMp3(byte[] mp3SoundByteArray) {
    try {

        File tempMp3 = File.createTempFile("kurchina", "mp3", getCacheDir());
        tempMp3.deleteOnExit();
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(tempMp3);
        fos.write(mp3SoundByteArray);
        fos.close();

        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(tempMp3);

        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(fis.getFD());

        mediaPlayer.prepare();
        mediaPlayer.start();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        String s = ex.toString();
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: what's the size of audio/video file

Comment: when am trying to play video songs more then 35MB and audio i tried with 70 MB file.

Comment: There is some issue with your code because I have played Video file of 78 mb in my code

Comment: Please show `OutOfMemoryException` which has the stacktrace which line is triggering the exception